# Integral using Monte Carlo Simulation yields incorrect result

Tags: python, montecarlo

I tried to compute integral of exp(x),  x in range [0,2] and sample from uniform dist. Somehow the integral result is exactly half of expected value. Does anyone know which part I made mistake? Thank you!

```
x_upLimit=2
max = np.exp(x_upLimit)

def f(x):
    return np.exp(x)

def P_samples(N):
    return np.random.uniform(0, x_upLimit, N)

def expectation_value(N):
    s = P_samples(N)
    return sum(f(s))/N

# xs = np.linspace(0, 2)
# plt.plot(xs, np.array([max]*len(xs)))
# plt.plot(xs, f(xs), label ='f(x)')

#estimated
expectation_value(1000000) #3.1938802618
#expected
expr = integrate(exp(x), (x,0,2))
expected = expr.evalf() #6.38905609893065
```

---

Answer my owner question. The integral from monte carlo was correct. The incorrect place is function used in "integrate". It should be

```
#expected
expr = integrate(exp(x)*1/(2-0), (x,0,2))
expected = expr.evalf() #3.19452804946533
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of the integral of exp(x) calculated between 0 and 2 is actually 6.389... (as given by the `integrate` function you use).

The problem lies in *your* `expectation_value` function, which should multiply the function average by the integration range (*i.e.* 2 in this specific case). See [here](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/mathematics-physics-for-computer-graphics/monte-carlo-methods-in-practice/monte-carlo-integration) for a thorough explanation.